# Read multiple parquet files using Apache Beam and ParquetIO

Tags: apache-beam, parquet

I need to read multiple parquet files in Apache Beam, all files are into the same folder. 
I've tried to read it using a wild card sign *.

I've managed to read separated parquet files using ParquetIO  and this is the snippet how I read one parquet file:

```
pipeline.apply(ParquetIO.read(SCHEMA).from(filePath + File.separator + "*"));
```

where the filePath is for example /path/xxx.parquet.

The snippet of the code how I've tried to read multiple parquet files is

```
pipeline.apply(ParquetIO.read(SCHEMA).from(folderPath + File.separator + "*.parquet" + File.separator + "*"));
```

where the folder path is for example /path/to/parquet/files/

I also tried without the last part File.separator + "*", but it's the same result. 
The info I got is:

> FileIO:654 - Matched 0 files for pattern
>   /path/to/parquet/files/*.parquet/ *

Also, I can have various numbers and names of parquet files.

Is it possible to read multiple parquet files using Apache Beam, because I found the way to read multiple txt files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to read multiple parquet files with `ParquetIO` since it uses `FileIO` under the hood. Just try to use another match pattern for that. In your case it could be something like this (I expect that `folderPath` is "/path/to"):

```
pipeline.apply(ParquetIO.read(SCHEMA).from(folderPath + File.separator + "parquet" + File.separator + "*" + File.separator + "*"));
```

or just double stars in the end:

```
pipeline.apply(ParquetIO.read(SCHEMA).from(folderPath + File.separator + "parquet" + File.separator + "**");
```

You can't use `.` as a part of glob pattern since it can be legitimate part of file path. Use `?` to match any single character or `*` to match any string, within a single directory. Also, “**” pattern matches any string, and crosses directory boundaries.

Comment: This one with double starts works for me. Thanks a lot. @Alexey Romanenko